# Java code coverage : method level unit test

Tags: java, unit-testing, code-coverage

Are there some tools or Eclipse plugin that could detect that a method hasn't been subject to a unit test (JUnit/TestNg)?

Thx in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[EclEmma](http://www.eclemma.org/) is an Eclipse plugin that does just that.

Comment: perfect! (+1). This is the tool I was dreaming about.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I've never used EclEmma so far and I thought it yields code coverage info only at code line level...

Answer (score 0):

IntelliJ gives you code coverage - no plugins required.  It reports % of lines covered by your tests and highlights which ones are executed and which ones have not.

Time to upgrade your IDE.